# Set a chart sheet to a worksheet variable

Tags: vba, excel

My code stops at the following line:

```
Dim wks As Worksheet
Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(vSheets(i, 1))
```

with the error:

```
Run-time error 13, type mismatch
```

However, while on this line I can enter:

```
? ThisWorkbook.Sheets(vSheets(i, 1)).Name
```

into the immediate window and get the result

```
Cashf
```

so obviously the worksheet is found based on the name vSheets(i, 1). Why can't I set it as a worksheet? Cashf is a chart that is created as a worksheet. Are those a different type of object than Worksheet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sheets is a collection of Worksheets and Charts. A chart and a worksheet are different types of objects. You should define wrk as a variant.

The following example prints all the sheet names in the workbook and their type

```
Dim s As Variant
For Each s In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    Debug.Print s.Name, TypeName(s)
Next
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using ThisWorkbook.Worksheets instead of ThisWorkbook.Sheets [if you need the variable to be a Worksheet.]

If not, try **not** declaring the type or declare it as a Variant.

Public Sub main()

```
Dim ws

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Debug.Print ws.Name, ws.Type

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)
Debug.Print ws.Name, ws.Type
```

End Sub

Comment: I want to include chartsheets as well